# Casting to raw type

Tags: java, generics, casting, raw-types

I am stuck with a code that I do not understand why it works. Assume that I create a generic interface `Foo<T>` as following:

```
interface Foo<T>{
   void set(T item);
}
```

Then I create a class called `Bar` which implements `Foo<String>` as following:

```
class Bar implements Foo<String>{ 
   @override
   public void set(String item){
      //useless body
   }
}
```

Based on this we can writes following code:

```
Bar bar = new Bar();
bar.set("Some string");
Foo rawFoo = (Foo) bar;
rawFoo.set(new Object()); // ClassCastException: Object cannot be cast to string
```

That last line is the one that I don't really get. As it's known that when using raw types the generic parameter types are converted to `Object`.
In this case the code compiles and we can pass Object to `set()` method. But how Java determines that it has to cast the Object to String at runtime?

Comment: [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) the second bullet point: *Insert type casts if necessary to preserve type safety.*

Comment: Let's say we call `item.charAt(0)` in the body of `Bar.set()`. What would you expect to happen when you call `set(new Object())`?

Comment: Of course we would expect some guarantee that only String can be passed to the set method. All the answers here actually point to the same concept, bridge methods. I will need to carefully read and understand bridge methods

Comment: @grustamli do you? Can't you just avoid raw types instead and continue to live in blissful ignorance? :)

Comment: @AndyTurner, no Sir I honestly cannot sleep unless I fully understand what I read. I could live with that ignorance once I didn't know anything about generics, but now it's too late :)

Comment: @grustamil my point was that the more important thing to do is to avoid raw types if at all possible: bridge methods are merely an implementation detail.

Comment: @AndyTurner, I agree with you. I was reading a section on specializing classes by delegation, then I saw a similar code to what I posted here. I couldn't comprehend how that worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you decompile `Bar` using `javap`:

```
class Bar implements Foo<java.lang.String> {
  Bar();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public void set(java.lang.String);
    Code:
       0: return

  public void set(java.lang.Object);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: aload_1
       2: checkcast     #2                  // class java/lang/String
       5: invokevirtual #3                  // Method set:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
       8: return
}
```

`void set(java.lang.Object)` is a synthetic bridge method. Note the `checkcast` instruction. The equivalent "real" code would look like:

```
public void set(Object object) {
  set((String) object);
}
```

The compiler created this method in order for the class to work under type erasure; the actual method doing the work is `set(java.lang.String)`, to which the bridge method delegates.

It is this bridge method which actually overrides the method in the base class. The method you declare with the `@Override` annotation is merely an overload.

Comment: Could you recommend me a good source where I can read raw types and bridge methods ?

Comment: @grustamli You can start with the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html).

Comment: @grustamil [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/3788176).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, what you are doing is just providing a reference to existing object, you are not creating a new object.

> When compiling a class or interface that extends a parameterized class
>   or implements a parameterized interface, the compiler may need to
>   create a synthetic method, called a bridge method, as part of the type
>   erasure process.

After type erasure your Foo becomes:

```
interface Foo{
   void set(Object item);
}
```

and your class becomes:

```
class Bar implements Foo{ 
   @override
   public void set(String item){
      //useless body
   }
}
```

After type erasure, the method signatures do not match.

Therefore, the Bar set method does not implement the Foo set method.

To solve this problem and preserve the polymorphism of generic types after type erasure, a Java compiler generates a bridge method to ensure that subtyping works as expected. For the Bar class, the compiler generates the following bridge method for set:

```
public void set(Object item){
    set((String) data);
}
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html

Comment: When writing code snippets, highlight the snippet and hit ctrl+k to turn it into a code block, with four spaces at the start of each line.

Answer (score 1):

Generics in Java are a compile-time type safety feature.  Because they were introduced in version 1.5, they had to be backwards-compatible with prior versions.  This allows you to use raw types -- a variable without type parameters referring to a class with type parameters.

At runtime, most of the type parameter information is erased, but not all of it.  In [this tutorial page about type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), we learn that the compiler will insert casts when necessary.

> - Replace all type parameters in generic types with their bounds or Object if the type parameters are unbounded. The produced bytecode, therefore, contains only ordinary classes, interfaces, and methods.
> - Insert type casts if necessary to preserve type safety.
> - Generate bridge methods to preserve polymorphism in extended generic types.

Here, the compiler creates a *bridge method* to preserve polymorphism at runtime, which takes an `Object`, casts its parameter to a `String`, then calls the real `set(String)` method.

When you call `rawFoo.set(new Object());`, because of polymorphism, this bridge method is called in `Bar`.  This is the implicit cast that you see here showing up as a `ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the answer to my question is bridge methods. I am currently reading the book, 'Java Generics and Collections' by Maurice Naftalin and Philip Wadler. I actually read a section on bridge methods, however it seems I didn't read it carefully. I am glad that all the answers had common point. Now, I will go and read that section again